# Sending keystrokes with PowerShell and including a percent sign in the text

Tags: vba, powershell, escaping, special-characters, sendkeys

I have this long string of characters I need to send exactly as show in the text file I am reading it from (`$token = Get-Content $token_txt`).  This string of characters has a few percent signs in it. They need to be included in the string of characters.  Every time I do a `SendKeys` using either wshell, VB, or WASP it removes the percent sign and the next two characters from the text.  I am sure its thinking its a special character and some keystroke command or something.  How do I get the system to ignore the percent signs and not treat them as special characters?

Here is an example of the string I am reading from the text file and its set to the variable `$token`:

```
YzY5FlNDItMjllctZjA4ZDVkNzUxNWM3LTE1MzMyMzMw%0AMTY2NDJ8VjBPd1BhT1JVSmtwWkxaZk1tRkNCbGNONzl5SndHb3YyQVZNVlNX%0AQWdMQT0%3D%0A
```

As you can see there are a few percent signs in the token however these need to be sent exactly as shown.  When I see it get sent it makes it

```
YzY5FlNDItMjllctZjA4ZDVkNzUxNWM3LTE1MzMyMzMwMTY2NDJ8VjBPd1BhT1JVSmtwWkxaZk1tRkNCbGNONzl5SndHb3YyQVZNVlNXQWdMQT0
```

Like I said I've tried wshell, VB, WASP to all send the keys to a PuTTY window and its not sending it correctly.

If I just have it display the variable `$token` in PowerShell it displays it properly with the percent signs.  Its only when I send the keys when it removes the special characters.

Here is the three ways I tried sending it

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('putty')
Sleep 1
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($token);

add-type -AssemblyName microsoft.VisualBasic
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("putty")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($token)

Select-Window putty | Send-Keys $token
Select-Window putty | Send-Keys "{ENTER}"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you are supposed to use a backtick ` to quote a special character.

Comment: I did try to add the backtick to the text file and it still removed the percent sign and the following two characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclosing the % in {} seems to do the trick

```
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("Test{%}Test");
```

[MSDN SendKeys Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of these characters, enclose it within braces ({}). For example, to specify the plus sign, use "{+}".

Add a replace method to your $token

```
$token = $token.Replace("%","{%}")
```

Comment: Adam you're amazing thats exactly what I needed!! Thank you!!